# Spring Boot ManyToMany presist nested data

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I'm currently working on my first Spring boot application where I'm trying to presist a ManyToMany relation between two entities. I'm currently experiencing an error when trying to save an entity to my endpoint.

User Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 16) 
    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name") 
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name = "game_participants",
            joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "user_id") },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "game_id") }
    )
    private List<Game> games;
}
```

Game Entity

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "game")
public class Game {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid") 
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @Column(length = 16) 
    @ApiModelProperty(required = false, hidden = true)
    private UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();

    @Column(name = "name") 
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "games")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

I'm working with OpenAPI(swagger), where I'm trying to save a new 'Game' entity. My issue is that it is expecting to get a payload structured like this:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "users": [
    {
      "games": [
        null
      ],
      "name": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don't really understand why it is nesting another game entity in my User entity.
What I'm really trying to achieve is something like this:

```
{
  "name": "string",
  "users": [
    {
      "name": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think you're confusing JSON-mapping from DB-Mapping. The `@ManyToMany` annotation is for DBA-Mapping, not a JSON-mapping/marshalling annotation.

Then, why is it nesting one object inside another one? The thing is easy, that's what it's called: circular-reference. Game refers to User, and user refers to Game. There are multiple ways to mitigate this, one of those is by lazy-loading, and add a response builder.

I think you could revisit how to design your mapping to database, and your mapping to json by looking at these links:

- https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many (java to db persist)
- https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/ (incoming-json to java object)

Answer (score 1):

To achieve

```
{
"name": "string",
"users": [
{
  "name": "string"
}
         ]
}
```

delete

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "games")
private List<User> users;
```

from Game class. But then you would not have a reference to users from game object.